# ActionListener() on JButton not working (even though I coded other buttons the same way)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I know similar questions have been asked but everyone's code is different and the solutions to their mistakes aren't really helping me to find a solution.

```
//Libraries
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class SliderGame implements ActionListener  {
    JLabel referenceLabel1;
    JLabel instruc1;
    JLabel preGame1;
    JButton gotIt1;
    JButton addPicture1;
    JPanel instructionsPanel1;
    JPanel gameboardFoundation1;

    public SliderGame(){

     //Image that shows user what their objective is
     referenceLabel1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Images/SliderEasy.jpg"));
     referenceLabel1.setBounds(100,150,300,300);
     referenceLabel1.setVisible(true);
     easyBackground.add(referenceLabel1);

     //"your objective" pregame = before the game starts
     preGame1 = new JLabel("Your objective:");
     preGame1.setBounds(500,150,300,100);
     preGame1.setFont(new Font ("Courier New", Font.ITALIC, 28));
     preGame1.setVisible(true);
     easyBackground.add(preGame1);

     //Tells you the instructions
     instruc1 = new JLabel ("<html>Use the mouse & click to move piece into 
     the blank spot to get the numbers in order, as shown on the left -- As 
     fast as you can!<html>");
     instruc1.setBounds(500, 190, 300, 200);
     instruc1.setFont(new Font ("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 20));
     instruc1.setVisible(true);
     easyBackground.add(instruc1);

     //Press to play
     gotIt1 = new JButton ("Got it!");
     gotIt1.setBounds(500, 375, 100, 50);
     gotIt1.setFont(new Font ("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12));
     gotIt1.setVisible(true);
     easyBackground.add(gotIt1);
     gotIt1.addActionListener(this);

     //Press to choose images from a library
     addPicture1 = new JButton ("Use Picture");
     addPicture1.setBounds(615, 375, 135, 50);
     addPicture1.setFont(new Font ("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12));
     addPicture1.setVisible(true);
     easyBackground.add(addPicture1);   
     addPicture1.addActionListener(this); 

     //Panel that holds the gameboard
     gameboardFoundation1 = new JPanel();
     gameboardFoundation1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,3,3));
     gameboardFoundation1.setBounds(100, 150, 300, 300);
     gameboardFoundation1.setOpaque(false);
     gameboardFoundation1.setVisible(false);
     easyBackground.add(gameboardFoundation1);
}

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource().equals(gotIt1)) {

        preGame1.setVisible(false);
        instruc1.setVisible(false);
        gotIt1.setVisible(false);
        addPicture1.setVisible(false);
        referenceLabel1.setVisible(false);

        gameboardFoundation1.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

I didn't include all of my code, so instances where it says mainFrame.add() for example, mainFrame exists, just I didn't add it to the question. The code works up until the point I click on the JButton gotIt1 and nothing changes. This is weird because I formatted all of the other buttons I used throughout my program and they work just fine.

I'm a beginner coder, especially at GUIs. I know my code isn't probably the cleanest but that's besides the point. Why isn't my button working!?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, I recommend using a `CardLayout` instead of trying to manage ALL the components within a single container

Comment: Your code snippet generates a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

Your button is not working for multiple reasons. For one, there is a syntax error (rooted in your actionPerformed method). You have an extra open curly brace and nothing closing the if statement. Secondly, with the code you have (assuming you fix the syntax error) you have no differentiation between the two actions. They both result in the same method being called because you have used the same action listener (which is also the class which is not recommended).

Fix your syntax error, then add code to your method that does a different action inside the if statement and put the current code in an else block (or vise versa).

Comment: I would say that the syntax error is a copy and paste error, since we're missing other parts of the code. The OP is determining the source of the action event through the use of `if (e.getSource().equals(gotIt1)) {`

Comment: If that's the case. The other action would do nothing as the if statement would most likely enclose the entire block (maybe).

Comment: I only worked on *"The code works up until the point I click on the JButton gotIt1 and nothing changes"* - meaning that the `gotit1` button is the issue - without more context, that's about as far as anyone can go :/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your available code...

```
referenceLabel1.setVisible(false);
```

is causing a `NullPointerException`.  If I change your `actionPerformed` method to something more like...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource().equals(gotIt1)) {

        preGame1.setVisible(false);
        instruc1.setVisible(false);
        gotIt1.setVisible(false);
        addPicture1.setVisible(false);
        //referenceLabel1.setVisible(false);

        gameboardFoundation1.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

The UI components are hidden (and if I change the background color of `gameboardFoundation1` and make it opaque, it is shown)

Now, I highly recommend taking the time to read through [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), especially [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) which has been designed to allow you to switch between multiple views easily

If this fails to solve you issue, then consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your issues

Comment: Hi, I totally forgot to add the code for referenceLabel1. I just edited my question. Thank you and I will try your suggestions. Next GUI I make I will definitely look into Card Layout. I just don't have the time since I need to have this program done for tomorrow.